# How do I make a Google Chrome theme responsive to light/dark system settings?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, themes

Google Chrome themes are defined by manifest.json, I'm trying to find out what to put there in order to make the theme responsive to light/dark system settings. I did not find any documentation, but Chrome is certainly capable to change its colors based on the settings, for example if i stick with the standard skin the bar is white in light mode, black in dark mode.

How do I apply that to a custom theme?

I tried looking for documentation, with the most recent official article from 2012: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/themes/ , no official answer seems to exist.

Comment: There's no way.

Comment: @wOxxOm could you elaborate on that? Why is the default skin responsive then?

Comment: The default "skin" is not a skin, it's a built-in implementation in C++.